# Nested postgres query

Tags: sql, postgresql, subquery

I have two working queries I can't seem to nest.

First one works:

```
SELECT * FROM accounts WHERE account = 'some_account';
```

Second works just fine:

```
SELECT COUNT(*) FROM accounts;
```

I would like to join these so that I get the count of accounts from the result of the first query and it would look something like this, but I can't do it.

```
SELECT COUNT(account) FROM (SELECT * FROM accounts WHERE account = 'some_account');
```

How would I do this?

Comment: So you want to know the number of rows where account = 'some_account'?

Comment: yes that's what want

Comment: The bottom one has `COUNT(account)` where the middle one has `COUNT(*)`, would that make a difference?

Comment: Why not simply `select count(*) from accounts WHERE account = 'some_account'`?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Either

```
SELECT COUNT(account) 
FROM (SELECT account 
      FROM accounts 
      WHERE account = 'some_account');
```

Or

```
SELECT COUNT(*) 
FROM accounts 
WHERE account = 'some_account';
```

Answer (score 1):

```
select count(case when account = 'some_account' then 1 else null end) as Count
FROM accounts
```